# Read/write OpenGL 3.2+ Framebuffer after shader processing

Tags: opengl

I have a program where I get the output of my shaders using glReadPixels, and I process that output with some separate library, and I need to write it back to the frame buffer.
I've tried to use glDrawPixels but it seems it isn't supported as of 3.2+.

This is how it goes

```
main loop
   ...
   ...
   glReadPixels(...)
   // Do some work
   ...
   ...
   // Write modified buffer to current frame buffer
   // Swap buffers
```

What OpenGL constructs are best for this scenario?

Comment: If you want to use `glDrawPixels`, you have to use a compatibility profile OpenGL context. See [18.1 Drawing Pixels](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.compatibility.pdf#page=669&zoom=100,168,526)

Comment: I set glfw to use the compatibility profile, but for some reason it is giving me trouble. I also want to run this on Mac OS. How about the following: Create a separate FBO, attach a texture. Render on default frame buffer, use glReadPixels, do work, bind separate FBO and copy to its attached texture, blit copy from separate FBO to default. What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I ended up choosing is as follows:

1.Create a first FBO and render the scene to it, off-screen
2.Read the FBO to CPU memory using glReadPixels
3.Do work
4.Write the image to a texture
5.Use a simple pass-through vertex and fragment shaders to display the texture to the viewport